# Is there an easy way to physically implement a simple digital circuit?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, programmable-logic, asic

I designed a digital circuit which, in total, has about 27-30 gates. Building that circuit in real life using a 74 series IC would mean using a lot of through hole/SMD chips, which wouldn't be feasible as I would like to fit that circuit in a small enclosure. I know how to program FPGA's (basic knowledge) using VHDL so I was wondering if there is a single electronic chip which I can program using a HDL so that I can create basic/small digital circuits without using tens of 74 Series IC's, but instead a single, programmable FPGA-like circuit? And what equipment would I need to program such a circuit?

EDIT: Preferably manageable packages, not a 100 pin smd package

Comment: Why don't you go for a micro-controller?

Comment: Because I want to use and learn something else

Answer (score 4):

You might be looking for an [CPLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_programmable_logic_device) or a [PAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_Array_Logic) which are programmable logic devices of less complexity than a FPGA and a quick search on digikey for CPLD shows that they are available in easy to use DIP packages from 20 pin to 44 pin

Comment: So how complicated is it to program a CPLD? I do have an FPGA development board, but I don't need to program it using JTAG, because it has an USB programmer. How hard is it to program using a JTAG programmer?

Comment: @Calin you can likely just use the JTAG programmer from your FPGA dev-board. See if you can disconnect the FPGA and access the pins. Otherwise buy a cheap one based on the FT2332 chip.